# Why DSpace SAFBuilder import not working for vernacular language like spanish, Urdu, Hindi etc?

Tags: java, excel, csv, office365, dspace

while working on vernacular language in CSV files after importing the file into DSpace using SAF Builder it shows symbols character. My CSV file is UTF-8 Unicode while I open it, there it shows symbol intent of showing in vernacular language.

Comment: Please consider answering your own question on how you solved it... it will be useful to future visitors... also please restore the question to its previous form.

Answer (score 0):

This is only for Window based user.

Prepared the excel sheet with all the Dublin-core metadata field. then save that excel sheet as CSV UTF-8 (Comma Delimited ad Closed it. Now, Open the same file that you save as CSV UTF-8 with **Open with** Option notepad, not Notepad ++. After Opening that again go to save as option choose **File name** type like yourfilename.csv and **Save as type** option choose all Files then encoding as UTF-8 not UTF-8 with DOM, and save it. Now, Go to you Safbuilder software and run the cmd command script like software path is C:\Users\xyz\SAFBuilder-master
open the CMD in same software path and run the bat file with use of -c CSVfilepath\CSVFileName.csv -z

It will convert and create a SAF file folder Simple Archive Folder with thumbnail and pdf.
How to import thumbnail and pdf same with bundle name.
In first column give the file name and bundle name that separeted by double underscore
blandino.pdf__bundle:ORIGINAL||blandino.jpg__bundle:THUMBNAIL

[image]